# How do you run `less` and have it run a search pattern automatically?

Tags: linux, unix, less

I'm trying to run `less` in Linux, and I want it to search for something immediately after launch.

It's basically like doing this:

```
$ less
```

Then press `'/'`, type a search pattern like `"^commit \w+$"`, then press enter, and press `'n'` to find each subsequent result.

I'd like less to be launched, and then search for a pattern. There doesn't seem to be anything in the man page about starting with a pattern, but perhaps you can send it commands like Vim.

Comment: Awesome, put this in your git config: `core.pager = less -cFRX --pattern='^commit'` and you'll be able to go to the next commit with the 'n' key right away.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the `man` page:

```
   -ppattern or --pattern=pattern
          The  -p  option  on the command line is equivalent to specifying
          +/pattern; that is, it tells less to start at the  first  occur-
          rence of pattern in the file.
```

This works as expected using the latest version of `less` (*436*).

Answer (score 18):

You can use + to send arbitrary commands.  E.g.:

```
less +/pattern
```

`-p PATTERN` (as posted by nik) is equivalent to `+/PATTERN`.

Comment: I prefer this answer, because it is more complete. The option `+/pattern` is equivalent to `--pattern=pattern`, but it can do more, such as to start less at the end of a file, do `less +G`. The `+` option gives you everything `-p|--pattern` does plus the entire set of other commands to run in less, so I say don't bother remembering `-p` and just use `+/` to search just as you would from inside less.

Answer (score 3):

You mean like?

> less -p PATTERN filename

That is in the manual.

Answer (score 3):

There are actually two ways to do this. As everyone else mentioned, you can use the `-p`/`--pattern` options:

```
less -p<pattern>
less --pattern=<pattern>
```

Your pattern will have to be wrapped in quotation marks since it contains a space.

However, there is actually a second way to do this:

```
LESS=-p<pattern> less
LESS=--pattern=<pattern> less
```

The second method has one distinct advantage. It can be used with other commands that use less for pagination!:

```
LESS=-p"^       read \[" man bash
```

This can quite literally be extended to search the bash man page for all builtin commands. I got a little carried away one day and ["fixed" man for bash builtins](https://github.com/adamjstewart/dotfiles/blob/d0e31a1f9aa7526ed27c16de4e48b2a3de1dec08/.bash_functions#L187).

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed somthing in the less manpage.

You could try :

```
less -p<pattern>
```

or

```
less --pattern=<patern>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is that when you run the `less` then type `&` and the `pattern` of your interest.

This way you can get ***only*** the lines that has your `pattern` of interest **not** all the lines. *Meaning shows only the matching lines*.

```
&/ <pattern_of_interest>
```